# In PyQt, how can a terminal be embedded in a window?

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, xterm

I have a small script that is designed to embed an xterm in a PyQt GUI. On Linux, it works, creating a GUI like this:

[image]

However, running the same script on OS X yields two windows like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to address this and prevent OS X from screwing up the GUI?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class embeddedTerminal(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.process = QProcess(self)
        self.terminal = QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.terminal)
        self.process.start('xterm', ['-into', str(self.terminal.winId())])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = embeddedTerminal()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [qtconsole](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole) front end for [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/index.html) and try to use the [bash kernel](https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel).  Depending on your end goal, I know it is possible to embed an [IPython kernel](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/tree/master/examples/embedding), in another application.